# uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a query in mongodb and I can't get my syntax correct. Any ideas about what I'm missing here?

```
db.users.update({"name": "Cristian Drilea"}, {$push:{favourites.books:"Animal Farm"}}) 
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after property id :
```

This is how the object I want to modify looks like
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be "favourites.books" (quoted)?

Comment: yeaah, it worked. thanks a lot!